# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module error on Angular.js App on Apache

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Apache server to host an angular app.
This is the index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/lib/angular/angular.js">
  </head>
  <script>
     myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
     
     myapp.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope){
    
          $scope.words = ['It','is','what','it','is']
     });
    
  </script>
  
  <body ng-app="myapp">

      <div ng-controller="indexCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="word in words">
          {{word}}
        </div>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I hit the html from the browser, it shows a blank page with this error :

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myapp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myapp' is not available!
>
> You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

What could be wrong?

Comment: this is because you are not closing script tag.

Comment: Wow. what a slip. thanks man!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is because of duplicate values inside array. I have added `track by $index` inside `ng-repeat` to resolve this issue.

**DOCS**: [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

**Modified code**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script>
     var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

     myapp.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope){

          $scope.words = ['It','is','what','it','is']
     });

  </script>

  <body ng-app="myapp">

      <div ng-controller="indexCtrl">

          <div ng-repeat="word in words track by $index">

             {{word}}

          </div>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have added track by $index inside ng-repeat because your array contains duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

Please include angularjs in body.

```
<script src="/lib/angular/angular.js">
```

Include this line in body. Hope it will works!

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<script>` part and the end of the body :

```
<body ng-app="myapp">

      <div ng-controller="indexCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="word in words">
          {{word}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <script>
          myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
          myapp.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope){
               $scope.words = ['It','is','what','it','is']
          });
    </script>
  </body>
```

that's a good practicte in HTML, and particularly in Angular to put the definition of your JS file just before the body ended